# How to convert request body from swagger.json to proper schema using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

How to convert requestbody in swagger.json to the format which is visible in UI? I need the snippet for internal project and the schema is complex with multiple $ref(s). Please advise

Comment: Could you provide examples of the input data and the output data that you want?